# What's the right way to import functions for suggested packages?

Tags: r, import, package, dependencies

Importing other packages' functions within one's own package is easy enough ([example](https://github.com/rempsyc/rempsyc/blob/main/R/reexports.R)), but that requires having a hard dependency (`Imports` in the `DESCRIPTION` file) on that package. In my case, it is a suggested package, so I am getting a warning: `'::' or ':::' import not declared` on R CMD check.

So right now, I am recreating the functions locally, but this is problematic as when both packages are loaded, there is another warning `The following objects are masked from [the other package]`. They're the same, so it's not a big issue, but enough to be annoying. I can't imagine there's not a better practice than this?

In case we need actual code for demo, here is the problematic imports for my package: https://github.com/rempsyc/lavaanExtra/blob/main/R/save_as_x.R

Comment: Looking at the package structure, I don't think you can have your cake and eat it too. You can *either* put `flextable` in `Imports:` **or** live with the masking warnings **or** tell your users that they have to call `flextable::<export_fun>()`. (Personally I don't see the big advantage of avoiding typing `library("flextable")` or `flextable::` ...)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Avoiding having the suggested package in `Imports` is more important than reexporting its functions, so that's not an option. The idea is that I have a suggested package that itself reexports some functions. So seems counterproductive to force import another package just because of the reexports of the other suggested dependency...

Comment: My point is that I just don't see how much you gain by having those functions part of your package rather than telling your users to load flextable themselves or use `flextable::` to access the functions. The functions won't be available anyway unless `flextable` is installed ...  but that's just my opinion, and maybe I'm missing the point. But your question does sound a bit like "how do I import without importing" ... ?

Comment: Good point. I will think about which of these options I like most. Thanks for your input.